# Set width of a table column to size of width of the header

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Am using primeng2 datatable and I would like to setup the width of the column to the header size.

So in my html I have:

```
<p-dataTable #dtselfcollectmonthly [exportFilename]="exportname" [rows]="10" [value]="rawdatatrucks">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of colheaders">
        <p-column [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" //setting width to 100% fails></p-column>
    </ng-container>
</p-dataTable>
```

As above by setting the width to 100% doesn't set the width of the column to the header size.

What else do I need to add?

Comment: Can you add image of your output grid?

Comment: @Vega Yes and marked it as correct

Comment: Have you set the width for the datatable?

Comment: I havent setup  specific width on the datatable but set it as [responsive]="true"

Comment: But only on the columns

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width of the table first, and then on ng-container instead of setting it on the column tag:

```
<p-dataTable .... [tableStyle]="{width: '380px','text-align':'center'}" ... >
  <ng-container style="width:100%" ...
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XbcdYi342KsSFRpY9jaV?p=preview) - it's an example one, not your actual code